# What is the diffusion limiting current density in comparison to rotating electrodes or fuel cells with pumps/stirrers?

Tags: electrochemistry

If an electrolytic fuel cell operates in an acidic liquid electrolyte and electrons are supplied to a catalytic electrode so that the protons in the liquid solution will react and produce hydrogen gas, how much is the performance of the fuel cell limited by letting the protons simply diffuse onto the catalyst instead of rotating the electrode or stirring the liquid? I read about diffusion limiting current density but I wonder whether practically, fuel cells operating based on simple molecular passive diffusion are extremely inefficient. Can you give me a difference in magnitude between the current density of a fuel cell based on passive diffusion and a fuel cell based on rotating electrode or stirring? Is it 2 times higher or 2,000 times higher etc?

Comment: The question is too broad. These will depend on the type of electrolyte, its viscosity, ionic conductivity, characteristics of the electrode, the stirring rate that you use and so on.